# How to format data in this array/json in php

Tags: php

I need to post data to api in this format

```
{
"id": "klsjldjldskjfl",
"user_ids": [
10139, 10008
]
}
```

How do I create data in the above format in PHP

```
 $x = [
         id: 'dsafsdfsdf'
         array('user_ids' => 33898932932 );
    ];
    $post_data = json_encode($x);
-----
-----
-----
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Comment: Please explain the issue? what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id: 'dsafsdfsdf'` is invalid array format, `user_ids` is an array, so:

```
$x = [
    'id' => 'dsafsdfsdf',
    'user_ids' => [1,2,3] 
];
$post_data = json_encode($x);
```